# Open chrome-extension:// url using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, google-chrome-extension, load

I search a lot of things about this issue.

I have a mini project and I want to Open a chrome-extension programmatically using javascript.

I want to open this url:

"[chrome-extension://hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/nhc.htm#url=https://www.ietab.net/ie-tab-documentation?from=chromeurl](http://chrome-extension://hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/nhc.htm#url=https://www.ietab.net/ie-tab-documentation?from=chromeurl)"

using javascript when I click on button.

Or if I put it in `<a href>` is ok, almost everybody said that it is not possible due to extension security policy.

It always redirects to `about:blank`.

this is my code

```
<a href="chrome-extension://hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/nhc.htm#url=http://192.168.40.155:81/doc/page/login.asp?_1531182510534">clickme</a>
```

Is it possible to turn the restriction off?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: since *"**almost** everybody said that it is not possible"*, that means you must have seen somebody that said it is possible

Comment: Links outside of extension's own page can't have chrome-extension protocol. The only workaround is to add a listener inside the extension script and then use chrome.tabs.create which is an extension API method available only in extensions.

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry for not complete explanation, the remaining others give some solutions, but still not working. Thank you for your reply.